# Android studio res/xml directory not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to include searchable configuration file in my project, In android documentation they have said to include this xml file in res/xml directory. But xml directory is not found.Do i need to create xml directory or add this xml file elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create xml directory under res folder like (RES-XML) put you Car.xml in  XML folder. I have added sample code for retrieving data from `xml/car.xml`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    private static String APP_TAG = "tag";
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textField);
        findViewById(R.id.readBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.cars);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                        String name = parser.getName();
                        String position = null;
                        String brand = null;
                        if((name != null) && name.equals("car")) {
                            int size = parser.getAttributeCount();
                            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                                String attrName = parser.getAttributeName(i);
                                String attrValue = parser.getAttributeValue(i);
                                if((attrName != null) && attrName.equals("position")) {
                                    position = attrValue;
                                } else if ((attrName != null) && attrName.equals("brand")) {
                                    brand = attrValue;
                                }
                            }
                            if((position != null) && (brand != null)) {
                                stringBuilder.append(position + ", " + brand + "\n");
                            }
                        }
                        textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                    }
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.e(APP_TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: But we still don't know if we have to create xml folder (and how)

Comment: You need to create xml directory manaually under res folder like (RES-XML) put you Car.xml in  XML folder
i have added sample code for retrieving data from xml/car.xml

Answer (score -1):

[Documentation says](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

> The first thing you need is an XML file called the searchable
> configuration. It configures certain UI aspects of the search dialog
> or widget and defines how features such as suggestions and voice
> search behave. This file is traditionally named searchable.xml and
> must be saved in the res/xml/ project directory.